# File type actions for ruby scripts

Tags: windows-xp

I just installed [the Ruby interpreter](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) and created the file test.rb.

In the Folder Options, I created the rb file type and an action called **Run** and assigned the application **C:\Ruby192\bin\ruby.exe "%1""** So It's possible for to get into the Windows XP command line and run the script simply by doing this:

```
C:\>test.rb
```

But when I need to send parameters to the script, I can't simply do the following:

> C:>test.rb parameter1 parameter2

I'll have to do the following instead:

> C:\Ruby192\bin\ruby.exe c:\test.rb parameter1 parameter2

I just noticed that I'm able to edit the action the following way to pass more parameters:

> C:\Ruby192\bin\ruby.exe "%1" "%2" "%3""

That allows me to give 2 parameters to the script, but for some cases I need to pass a handful of parameters and it doesn't seem right for me to append "%5" "%6" "%7" ad nauseam.

What's the canonical way to do it?

Comment: (Totally unrelated: I _never_ got the point of using `C:\Ruby192` instead of simply `C:\Ruby` or `C:\Program Files\Ruby`, *as the default installation path...* I mean, it breaks stuff even after a minor upgrade.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found it for the VBS files!

> C:\WINDOWS\System32\WScript.exe "%1" %*

I did the same for RB files and it works!

> C:\Ruby192\bin\ruby.exe "%1" %*